# How can I access my localhost on my computer from my Android device?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web application written in ASP.NET MVC 5. I simply can open it from the browser with this `localhost:14920` in my computer, but I want to access the same application from my Android device's browser while my laptop and Android device are in the same network. I don't know how to access it from Android.

***Note***: when I type `127.0.0.1` in the Android browser I can access the [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) server, but when I type `127.0.0.1:14920` it prints `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Host your app in IIS instead of IISExpress...seems like your app is running in IIS express.

Comment: yes it is on IIS Express. do you think it is the problem?

Comment: I do. Try hosting in IIS and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try with replacing **127.0.0.1** with your [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address.

Comment: the same thing happened when i replaced ip

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) in the past, when needing to hit my development machine, or have someone else hit it. It is a very useful tool and very simple to install.

Once you download it, it's just a simple command line:

https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

```
ngrok http 80
```

(That is for traffic on port 80) Since your port above looks different it would be:

```
ngrok http 14920
```

That will give a URL that you can hit or any machine or device.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IISExpress for remote access

http://www.ryadel.com/en/iis-express-allow-external-requests-remote-clients-devices/

or just change the hosting to IIS as the earlier commenter mentioned.